# Prints the string of a struct

Tags: c

Something went wrong when I tried to print the string "descpt". Could someone help me please.
Here is my code:

```
struct Article {
    int a;
    int b;
    const char *descpt[20];
};

void Print(Article * data) {
    printf("The article number is %d\n", data->a);
    printf("The quantity is %d\n", data->b);
    printf("The article number is %s\n", data->descpt[20]);
}

int main() {
    Article data;
    data.a = 10;
    data.b = 20;
    data.descpt[20] = "Articles";
    Print(&data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the struct supposed to hold 20 strings, or one string with 20 characters?

Comment: there is an obvious buffer overflow. you can access `data->descpt[0]` up to `data->descpt[19]`. `data->descpt[20]` is out of the array and assigning it can lead to unexpected results. That being said, I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct Article {
    int a;
    int b;
    char descpt[20];
};

void Print(Article * data) {
    printf("The article number is %d\n", data->a);
    printf("The quantity is %d\n", data->b);
    printf("The article number is %s\n", data->descpt);
}
int main()
{
    Article data;
    data.a = 10;
    data.b = 20;
    strncpy_s(data.descpt, "Articles", strlen("Articles"));
    Print(&data);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read a little about char* array, it either has to be initialized or dynamically allocated, unless you point to an existing char array/string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You wanted something like this ?

```
struct Article {
    int a;
    int b;
    const char descpt[20]; /* array of max 19chars+terminator\0 */
};

void Print(Article * data) {
    printf("The article number is %d\n", data->a);
    printf("The quantity is %d\n", data->b);
    printf("The article number is %s\n", data->descpt);
}
int main()
{
    Article data;
    data.a = 10;
    data.b = 20;
    strcpy(data.descpt,"Articles");
    Print(&data);
    return 0;
}
```

For `strcpy()` you have to `#include <string.h>`